# Can I read the Quraan during menses from cell phone?

Tags: quran, women, menses

I am doing hifz. I have some doubts to clear. Can I read quraan during menses from cell phone? Because if I don't read, I forget what I have memorized.

Answer (score -1):

some scholars say you can’t and others say you can.but u should not be reading the Quran while a women is on her menses.you are able to listen to it but reciting it you have to be clean but when a women is on her menses she is not clean

Comment: Any strong evidence?